# Shopify API: Is there a way to determine whether or not an order came from Shopify POS?

Tags: shopify

Shopify introduced POS recently: http://www.shopify.com/pos

I wonder whether Shopify order JSON somehow (implicitly?) distinguishes orders created at POS from orders from orders created at Shopify site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the source_name attribute of the Order response, http://docs.shopify.com/api/order. This will be "web" or "pos".